# Connecting OverCharging kit with charger

Tags: charger

I Have one battery of 12V and 3.5 A. I purchased charger whose output is 12V and 3A. I also purchased overcharging kit. But dont know how to connect the overcharging kit with charger.
You can see pics of overcharging kit here.

[image]
[image]
**Updates**

Overcharging Kit means it is a kit placed next to your charging terminals. This kit will take care of your battery, if battery is fully charged it will disconnect the charging from battery to avoid over charging. It is locally made and no manual provided with it.

I have mentioned the terminals that needs to be connected with charger and battery. I have confusion which one to be connected with charging wires and which to be connected with battery terminals.
[image]

Comment: Welcome. There are a number of problems with your question as posed, but basically, I don't think most engineers understand what you mean by an "overcharging kit". Do you have any links or documentation that we could look at?

Comment: What's an overcharging kit? It sounds like something undesirable, like an LED burning-out kit.

Comment: Read The Fine Manual which you should have received if you obtained this device from a reputable supplier. (And it is bad practice to overcharge a battery.)

Comment: Overcharging Kit means it is a kit placed next to your charging terminals. This kit will take care of your battery, if battery is fully charged it will disconnect the charging from battery to avoid over charging.

It is locally made and no manual provided with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your board has a relay with three contact terminals - marked `NC` (normally closed), `NO` (normally open), and `COM` (common). When the relay is 'normal' (not operated) `COM` connects to `NC`. When it is operated `COM` connects to `NO`.

You should connect battery positive to `COM` and charger positive to `NC`. When battery voltage is low (yellow LED lit) the relay is off and the charger is connected to the battery via `NC`~`COM`. As the battery charges its voltage rises, eventually causing the relay to operate (green LED lit) and disconnecting the charger from the battery.

If you want to automatically power a load after the battery is charged then connect the load's positive lead to `NO`. This will connect the battery to the load until its voltage goes low. Then the relay will turn off again, disconnecting the load and reconnecting the charger.

The diagram below shows how to wire it up. I have included a simplified example circuit (without LEDs etc.) to illustrate the internal connections of your board.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDOMUG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

One problem you might have with a 3.5A charger and 3Ah battery is the charging current may be too high. This could cause the battery's voltage to rise rapidly so it gets disconnected before it gets a full charge. A 3Ah lead-acid battery should be charged at no more than 0.3A (10 hour charge rate). You can reduce the charging current by adding a resistor in series with the charge lead. Alternatively you could try using an incandescent light bulb. eg. 6V 3W indicator lamp.

Comment: And what about Negative Terminals of Battery and Charger? Where to connect them.
Secondly how much value of resistance will be sufficient in my case.

Comment: Charger - goes to battery -, as normal :). The resistance required depends on the charger's float voltage, so you may have to experiment to get the best value. For a rough calculation, measure the open-circuit charger voltage, subtract 13.8V and divide by 0.3A (eg. 18V-13.8V = 4.2V, / 0.3A = 14 Ohms). A lamp works better because its resistance automatically increases as it gets brighter, so the current doesn't vary as much as the voltage difference between charger and battery changes.

Comment: @BruceAbbott they would also need a >1.26W resistor (i.e. a 1.5 or 2W), which is somewhat larger than most (or a few in parallel, say 4x 56 ohm)